# Use fetch_feed(); Totally Outside of WordPress?

Tags: php, feed

I have used `fetch_feed()` many times with WordPress Project. Now I am working on non WP site.

So is there way to use `fetch_feed()` totally Outside of WordPress? What **WordPress Core files** should I copied to my workplace?

Comment: if you just want that one function you can look here to see how it works  https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.7.3/src/wp-includes/feed.php#L671

Comment: It uses [SimplePie](https://github.com/simplepie/simplepie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use directly the wordpress functions by just copying only core files of wordpress. 
You can refere this link also so you get some hint :- https://davidwalsh.name/wordpress-recent-posts